# JSON.stringify() is this object and function standard to javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have never seen it before until today and it seems to just work without including any .js or framework. is this a standard object in javascript? if so where can I find the documentation for it and other uncommon Objects that are available in javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you need to learn about [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @Alnitak The OP did not ask for the exact specification. Plus reading that is sometimes impossible to know exactly what is going on. MDN does a great job making it work, plus normally offers pollyfills in the explanation. You do not get that with the spec.

Comment: He mentioned "standard objects".  Those are defined in the specification, and plenty exist in MDN which are not "standard".  Otherwise, yes, I also use MDN for most reference purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the ES5 specification.  See http://es5.github.io/ for the whole annotated spec and for this function specifically see http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.3

See also http://caniuse.com/#search=json for a browser support matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. It's a standard object, in common use and works in all current browser versions. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

The only time you'll have a problem with it is in old IE versions; if you need to support them, you'll need to use a polyfill library like [this one](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).